# Which operator can implement a fermionic Bogoliubov Transformation?

Tags: operators, fermions, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

In bosonic systems (for example in Quantum Optics), two-mode Bogoliubov transformations are implemented via squeezing operators as $$\hat{S}_2(\xi)=\exp(\xi^{*}\hat{a}\hat{b}-\xi\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{b}^\dagger),$$ with $\xi=re^{i\theta}$, such that $$\hat{S}_2^\dagger(\xi)\hat{a}\hat{S}_2(\xi)=\hat{a}\cosh(r)-e^{i\theta}\hat{b}^\dagger\sinh(r),$$ $$ \hat{S}_2^\dagger(\xi)\hat{b}\hat{S}_2(\xi)=\hat{b}\cosh(r)-e^{i\theta}\hat{a}^\dagger\sinh(r).$$

I'd like to know:

- Is there an equivalent operator $\hat{S}_2^{\text{fermion}}(\xi)$ that can implement Bogoliubov transformations in fermionic creation/annihilation operators? What is its expresion?
- If it exists, is its interpretation equivalent to that of the squeezing operator in bosonic systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When    $\hat a$, $\hat a^\dagger$, $\hat b$, $\hat b^\dagger$  obey the fermion algebra
$$
\{ \hat a, \hat a^\dagger\}= \{ \hat b, \hat b^\dagger\}=1, \quad \{ \hat a, \hat a\}=\{ \hat b, \hat b\}=\{ \hat a, \hat b\}= \{ \hat a, \hat b^\dagger\}=0,
$$
we have $\hat a^2 =(\hat a^\dagger)^2=0$, so  there is no  fermion analogue of the boson   single-mode squeezing operator.
We can, however,  still construct a  two-mode  operator
$$
U[z]=\exp\{z \hat a^\dagger \hat b^\dagger - z^* \hat b\hat a\}\nonumber\\
= \exp\{(e^{i\theta} \tan |z|) \hat a^\dagger\hat  b^\dagger\} \exp\{(\ln\cos |z|)[ (\hat a^\dagger \hat a+{\textstyle \frac 12})+( \hat b^\dagger \hat b+{\textstyle \frac 12 })]\}\exp\{(-e^{-i\theta} \tan |z|) \hat b \hat a\}
$$
which      implements a  Bogoliubov-Valatin transformation
$$
U[z]\hat a U^\dagger[z] = (\cos |z|) \hat a - (e^{i\theta}\sin |z|) \hat b^\dagger, \nonumber\\
U[z]\hat b U^\dagger[z] =  (e^{i\theta}\sin |z|) \hat a^\dagger +(\cos |z|) \hat b.  
$$
The  right-hand-side  is now a compact  ${\rm SU}(2)$ rotation rather than a non-compact ${\rm SU}(1,1)$ transformation.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I've been trying to prove the decomposition that you make in the second equality of the second formula ($exp\{z\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{b}^\dagger-z^{*}\hat{b}\hat{a}\}=\exp\{(e^{i\theta}\tan|z|)\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{b}^\dagger\}...$) but I'm not really achieving it. I've tried with the Zassenhaus formula but since none of the commutators vanishes it's difficult to see anything there. Could you tell me where can I find a derivation or how to proceed?

Comment: I think i just looked it up and assumed that it works like the Bose case!  That you can find on page 8 in our recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.07059.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look and try to follow the analogous derivation for the fermionic case. Thank you!